# How to Enable the intellesense in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

how do I need to Enable Runtime intellesense in my VS2010.

I am not agetting any intellesense support until i do Control+space.

can any body help me out how to enable this feature.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have disabled Intellisense.

Take a look here for a solution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/01/how-to-turn-off-automatic-intellisense-vstipedit0054.aspx

Also, pressing CTRL+J will manually enable intellisense.